# How can I add rows to a table?

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, html-table

I am trying to get data form a server this is a long array of objects, something like:

```json
{
  "id": ,
  "product": "Candy",
  "Country": "",
  "date": "",
  "amount": ,
  "image": "candy.jpg"
  "id": ,
  "product": "Chips",
  "Country": "",
  "date": "",
  "amount": ,
  "image": "chips"
}
```

As you can see above, this is a row after row, I have a function in Javascript where I get the data from the server and put it in a table. But it gives me just all the data without doing it in separate rows.

```sh
Candy Africa June 2022 75 kg candy.jpg Chips America July 2022 65 kg chips.jpg
```

So at the end I want a table like this:

(Imagine as a table)

```sh
Product  Country  Date       Amount  Image
Candy    Africa   June 2022  75 kg   candy.jpg
Chips    America  July 2022  65 kg   chips.jpg
```

This is my code now:

```js
function createTable() {
  $(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
      $.ajax({
        url: "LINK",
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',

        success: function (data) {
          $("#inputTable").html(data);

          $(data).each(function (index, info) {

            $('#inputTable').append('<td>' + info.product +  '</td>') +
            $('#inputTable').append('<td>' + info.country + '</td>')  +
            $('#inputTable').append('<td>' + info.date + '</td>')  +
            $('#inputTable').append('<td>' + info.amount + '</td>' ) +
            $('#inputTable').append('<td>' + info.image  + '</td>')

          });
        }
      });
    }, 1);
  });
}
```

Comment: Why are you concatenating jQuery method calls with `+`?

Answer (score 2):

Each object needs to be in a separate table row.

To do this, place each object's `<td>` elements within a single `<tr>` element.

```js
const inputTable = $('#inputTable');

// add heading to table
inputTable.empty();
inputTable.append(`
  <tr>
    <th>Product</th>
    <th>Country</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Amount</th>
    <th>Image</th>
  </tr>
`);

// add each row to table
$(data).each(function (index, info) {
  
  inputTable.append(`
    <tr>
      <td>${info.product}</td>
      <td>${info.country}</td>
      <td>${info.date}</td>
      <td>${info.amount}</td>
      <td>${info.image}</td>
    </tr>
  `);
  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The data from the server is not correct JSON, it should be an array of objects:

```
[{
  "id": 28252,
  "product": "Candy",
  "Country": "Africa",
  "date": "june 2022",
  "amount": 75,
  "image": "candy.jpg"}.{
  "id": 28252,
  "product": "Chips",
  "Country": "America",
  "date": "july 2022",
  "amount": 65,
  "image": "chips"
}]
```

However, if you have no control over how the data is formatted then you can rebuild the data into the correct format, from a string.

I might do this by searching for ,"id" in the string and replacing it with '},{"id"'.  The comma is so we get every one except the first "id".

You also need to add  the array indicator at the beginning of the json string, something like:

```
function createTable() {
  $(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
      $.ajax({
        url: "LINK",
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',


        success: function (data) {
          $("#inputTable").html(data);  //Not sure what this line is for? See the raw data?
     
          data = "[" + data + "]"; //it's an array
           data = data.replace(',"id"','},{"id"');     
          $(data).each(function (index, info) {

            $('#inputTable').append('<td>' + info.product +  '</td>') +
              $('#inputTable').append('<td>' + info.country + '</td>')  +
              $('#inputTable').append('<td>' + info.date + '</td>')  +
              $('#inputTable').append('<td>' + info.amount + '</td>' ) + 
              $('#inputTable').append('<td>' + info.image  + '</td>') 


            
          });
        }
      });
    }, 1);
  });
}
```